# Change color of textview in viewlist depend on textview value

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview and custom adapter extending SingleTypeAdapter for it.  The listview contains textview(s). Whenever the number value in the textviews are changed the text color should also change. Eg. if textview change to unsigned number the color should be red otherwise yellow. How can I do that if I want best performance ?

I'm only interested in changing the color between red and white for aplied only to 3 viewtexts fields (change, percentChange, price). How do I do that ?

My adapter:

```
/**
 * Adapter to display a list of stock quotes
 */
public class StockListAdapter extends SingleTypeAdapter<CurrentStock> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");

    /**
     * @param inflater
     * @param items
     */
    public StockListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<CurrentStock> items) {
        super(inflater, R.layout.stock_quote_list_item);

        setItems(items);
    }

    /**
     * @param inflater
     */
    public StockListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this(inflater, null);

    }

    /*@Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        final String id = getItem(position).getObjectId();
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(id) ? id.hashCode() : super
                .getItemId(position);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected int[] getChildViewIds() {
        return new int[] { R.id.symbol, R.id.exchange, R.id.price, R.id.companyName, R.id.change, R.id.percentChange };
    }

    @Override
    protected void update(int position, CurrentStock currentStock) {
        setText(0, currentStock.getSymbol());
        setText(1, currentStock.getExchange());
        setText(2, currentStock.getPrice().toString());
        setText(3, currentStock.getCompanyName());
        setText(4, currentStock.getChange().toString());
        setText(5, currentStock.getPercentChange());
    }

}
```

And the xml file for the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exchange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyName"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_light_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyName"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/exchange"/>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/table_text_selector"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/price"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentChange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/table_stock_change_text"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/change"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/change"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/change"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code so you can get a relevant answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The code in `getView` will be even easier and will not get into trouble with parsing text to numbers. See the new code snippet.

In your `StockListAdapter` add the `getView()` method to override the behaviour, when a new stock item is shown.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View line = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    // Set price, change and %change to red/white
    ((TextView) line.findViewById(R.id.price)).setTextColor((currentStock.getPrice() < 0d)? 0xFFFF0000:0xFFFFFFFF);
    ((TextView) line.findViewById(R.id.change)).setTextColor((currentStock.getChange() < 0d)? 0xFFFF0000:0xFFFFFFFF);
    ((TextView) line.findViewById(R.id.percentChange)).setTextColor((currentStock.getPercentChange() < 0d)? 0xFFFF0000:0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

Some remarks:

- Best performance is relative. With this solution the checks and settings are only done as often as necessary. From this point of view it is the most efficient solution.

Comment: I updated the xml layout file which includes a RelativeLayout with TextFields. Please update your solution. I can't get it to work because first view is RelativeLayout not TextView. Why is the TextWatcher solution not better then your solution ?

Comment: Thx. I choosed the code with textwatcher since the texts is changed anytime and the color should follow. I think the listener is bit more quick ? Btw, When will the getView method be called ?

Comment: I'm travelling. Hopefully the changes are right. I cannot test it. If I understand your problem right, then you know what values to print (and if they're pos or neg) before you bring them to the screen. Therefore you dont need to print your values to the text view just to read them again and parse them and decide for the color. I suggest to give then the color right when they're printed.

Comment: Well, if you can test both for performance you should get the difference. If you understand what the system must do inside, you should understand the difference: if you can omit calls like the calls to listeners - that's the fastest way to handle things.

Comment: ok, thank you very much :) I will test it and come back for accepting the solution again.

Comment: How do you obtain the object "currentStock" in the getView method ?

Comment: Hi jboi, it is not solved yet. I think your solution is more 
appropriate for my task but before I can make it work I need to know how you get the object "currentStock" inside getView() method ???

Comment: Hi, I actually found how to get the "currentStock" by calling getItems().get(position) and that worked! I make use of your solution since it is simpel and quick and fullfill my requirements. Thanks and good day! :)